# Magento свой contact us

Tags: magento

Всем привет, никогда не работал с Magento дали тестовое. В тестовом нужно расширить contact us сделать запись в бд и т.д. сделать как отдельный Magento Extension. Может у кого есть пример или статья как сделать свой Magento Extension или как правильно расширить contact us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример:

Создаем модуль

> Vendor_StoreContacts

Переписываем контроллер, конфиг с переписанным контроллером модуля контактов

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Vendor_StoreContacts>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Vendor_StoreContacts>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <contacts>
            <rewrite>
                <data>Vendor_StoreContacts_Helper_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </contacts>
    </helpers>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <contacts>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_StoreContacts before="Mage_Contacts">Vendor_StoreContacts</Vendor_StoreContacts>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contacts>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Тут ещё переписан хелпер

Добавляем в контроллер(в наш) новый функционал, если нужно, например валидация касомных полей

> ..app/code/local/Vendor/StoreContacts/controllers/IndexController.php

Изменяем шаблон контактной формы(подставлякем свой через слои или же просто меням в текущей теме существующий)

---

Если нужно ещё и записывать в БД то создаем таблицу т.к. стандартный модуль контактов не ведет запись данных он просто отправляет на указанную в панели администратора почту.

---

На самом деле просто так тут все не описать(или выйдет очень много текста), но выше я написал примерную последовательность действий и если решить каждую задачу по отдельности в то в общем будет тот результат который нужен.

При этот нужно будет понять, upgrade/install скрипты, созлание модуля, переопределение классов в CMS Magento и т.д.